# Typescript check if promise body does not call `resolve`

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, es6-promise

Is there any typescript config option or some workaround to check if there is no `resolve` called in `new Promise` callback?

Assume I have a promise

```js
new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        // do some stuff
        // but not calling resolve()
    } catch (e) {
        reject(e)
    }
})
```

I want typescript to warn me that I did not call `resolve()`. Is it possible?

I know that I can use `noUnusedParameters`, but there are a couple of situations where I still need unused parameters (e.g. `request` inside of `express.Hanlder`, where I only use `response`, etc.)

Comment: I assume you want compile-time checks and no run-time hacks. Correct?

Comment: @k0pernikus actually yes, but if there is no compile-time solution, run-time solution will be also helpful

Comment: You'll be happier if you can put most of your logic into an `async` function and call that. If you forget to return a value from an async function (the equivalent of forgetting to call `resolve`) then it will show up in TypeScript's inferred return type (it will be `Promise<T | undefined>` instead of `Promise<T>`).

Comment: Actually every situation when it is possible to check that is a situation where `new Promise(` is not the right solution!

Comment: @danvk yes, you're right, but `async / await` does not provide as powerful error handling as it is inside the promise callback [(see examples section)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) - and this is true, I actually went to `return new Promise(...)` from `async / await` after couple of `unhandledRejection`s

Comment: @Lux cannot agree with you. See my comment about error handling above

Comment: @Limbo What do you mean with async / await not having as powerful error handling? You can just throw within an async function and it will be turned into a rejection for you.

Comment: @k0pernikus any rejected `await` inside of `async` function will not `throw`, but just reject that will cause `unhandledRejection`. Catching it through `try / catch` and throwing it inside `catch` block is actually weird and also it will cause to lost extra information from rejection

Comment: Looks like a different question. Do you maybe want to ask it? Because you're certainly doing something wrong. So just ask a new question how you can avoid the `unhandledRejection` with some code and what you've tried. I'm sure we'll figure it out.

Comment: @Lux well, the question is clear, I think. If there is no solution - ok then, I will just add linter warning on unused variables.

Comment: I just want to help. But I can guarantee you: `new Promise(async` is *always* a bad idea. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). So your question is a X/Y Problem.

Comment: you can only write custom eslint rule for this

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov yeah, considering to do it, thank you :)

Comment: For anybody "antipattern" mates - read [this](https://medium.com/@JonasJancarik/handling-those-unhandled-promise-rejections-when-using-javascript-async-await-and-ifee-5bac52a0b29f) and you probably will understand me (but I actually don't hope so)

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible. Knowing whether code calls a certain function (`resolve` in this case) is just as hard as the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). There is proof that no algorithm exists that can always determine this.

To illustrate, let's assume that the algorithm for determining whether a function calls `resolve` exists, and is made available via the function `callsResolve(func)`. So `callsResolve(func)` will return `true` when it determines that `func` will call `resolve` (without actually running `func`), and `false` when it determines that `func` will *not* call `resolve`.

Now image this `func`:

```
function func() {
    if (!callsResolve(func)) resolve();
}
```

... now we have a paradox: whatever this call of `callsResolve` returned, it was wrong. So for instance, if the implementation of `callsResolve` would have *simulated* an execution of `func` (synchronously) and determines that after a predefined timeout it should return `false`, the above is a demonstration of a function that calls `resolve` just after that timeout expired.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. I meant I want to be warned  if there is **no one** resolve called (like if `resolve` still unused), but for now I understand that the best solution will be to add an extra rule to my linter that will highlight unused parameters) Thank you for your answer

Comment: Yes, but also imagine `if (false) resolve();`. That effectively references `resolve`, but it will never execute. And that is just the most simple case. This can be more complex, so that you cannot really see whether `resolve` will be called or not.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get to a compile time check is to use async / await syntax.

If you don't want to use that, you could timeout your promises, though you would have to do that with each of your promise after / when you are creating them.

A solution could look like this:

```
export const resolveAfterDelay = (timeout: number) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, timeout));

export const rejectAfterDelay = async (timeout: number) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(`Promise timed out as resolve was not called within ${timeout}ms`), timeout));

};

export const timeoutPromise = <T>(timeout: number) => async (p: Promise<T>): Promise<T> => {
    return Promise.race([p, rejectAfterDelay(timeout)]);
};

const timeoutAfter1s = timeoutPromise(1e3);
const timeoutAfter10s = timeoutPromise(10e3);

timeoutAfter10s(resolveAfterDelay(3e3)).then(success => console.log("SUCCESS IS PRINTED")).catch(console.error); // works
timeoutAfter1s(resolveAfterDelay(3e3)).then(success => console.log("NEVER REACHED")).catch(console.error); // aborts

const neverResolvingPromise = new Promise(() => {
});

timeoutAfter1s(neverResolvingPromise).catch(console.error); // promise never resolves but it will be rejected by the timeout
```

It makes use of `Promise.race`. Basically, whatever first resoves or rejects will be returned. We want to always reject a Promise if it does not resolve in time.

You would always have to wrap your Promise on creation like

```
timeoutAfter10s(new Promise(...));
```

And you would have to adapt the timeout according to your use case.

Comment: Sounds good despite it is a runtime solution. Also it possibly could help to find weak (in meaning of execution time) places of code. Thank you